# Create mountpoint and mount block device with a single command?

Tags: command-line, mount

How do I mount a block device using only one command?

Such as `mount sdb1` *(create and select directory automatically)*
or *`mount sdb1 /mnt/USB1/`*. (**create directory automatically in one step.)**

Linux sometimes does not mount automatically.

Comment: After creating `/mnt/USB1` you shouldn't need to create it again. Have a look into `fstab` for mount points you use often

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What command does nemo use to mount drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394320/what-command-does-nemo-use-to-mount-drives)

Comment: Automounting is actually a thing, and has been for many years now.

Comment: You can do it with `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sd...` in Ubuntu. `alias udm='udisksctl mount --block-device'` to mount a disk with just 3 letters and no root privileges needed.

Comment: @undercat That's the solution. Do you consider posting it as answer, or should I?

Comment: @neverMind9 I'm glad this helped! Your quesiton is currently locked because several users were of the opinion it was "opinion-based". If it does get unlocked in the future, you can feel free to use my comment as the basis for a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add a function to the shell initialization file of your choice:

```
function qmount() {
    # qmount DEVICE DIR
    sudo sh -c 'mkdir -p "/mnt/$2" && mount "/dev/$1" "/mnt/$2"' sh "$1" "$2"
}
```

Comment: Use `mkdir -p "/mnt/$2"` to avoid having to test for existence. And you can't mount if the `mkdir` failed. E.g. `sudo sh -c 'mkdir -p "/mnt/$2" && mount "/dev/$1" "/mnt/$2"' sh "$1" "$2"` (also note quoting and properly passing arguments to the child shell).

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah, didn't know that `-p` also ignored existing target dirs. And thanks for the long version, was too lazy to figure out the parameter passing stuff :-)